# Converted Array from Object (with properties) returns 0 length

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this code in my javascript file:

```
var items = {
    first: 'Item 1',
    second: 'Item 2',
    third: 'Item 3'
};
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(items);

console.log(arr.length);
```

I want to convert an object into an array. My question is, when the object was converted into array, why does javascript return `0` when the object already has properties? I hope someone could help me and if anyone wouldn't mind, I want it to be corrected without using jQuery.

Comment: Array's are objects with numbers as the key names, and length property.... your object has no properties with numbers as keys nor a `length` property so you get an empty array

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice.call()` is only useful with an array-like object, but your object isn't array-like.

Comment: What is expected result? An array of objects, or an array of values reflecting object values?

Comment: I'm guessing he expected `['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']`

Comment: Your object has no `length` property, so it becomes an empty array, of course.

Comment: @guest271314 the result i'm expecting is an array with keys and values like associative arrays in PHP

Comment: @jst16 Can you include textual representation of expected result at Question?

Comment: associative arrays like in PHP: `[first => 'Item 1', second => 'Item 2', third => 'Item 3']`

Comment: @jst16 `arr1` at the second example at stacksnippets represents expected result, yes?

Comment: yes. with key-value pairs

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to create an array of arrays of properties, values from original object or an array of objects reflecting properties, values of original object.

> The `Object.entries()` method returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable property `[key, value]` pairs, in the same order as that
>   provided by a `for...in` loop (the difference being that a for-in loop
>   enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

```js
var items = {
    first: 'Item 1',
    second: 'Item 2',
    third: 'Item 3'
};

var arr = Object.entries(items);

console.log(arr);

var arr1 = Object.entries(items)
           .map((value, index) => {
              return {[value.shift()]: value.pop()}                    
           });

console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: Probably worth while to point out that *Object.entries* is an experimental technology and not part of ECMAScript (currently 7th edition) yet.

Comment: @RobG There is a [polyfill](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries) available; [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Browser_compatibility) at chomium 51+, firefox 47+. Alternatively,  `Object.keys()` with `Array.prototype.map()` can be utilized to return same result.

Comment: When I typed `console.log(typeof arr)`, it returned `object`, not `array`. Is it possible to convert it into a real array?

Comment: @jst16 `Array` is an object in `javascript`. Use `console.log(Array.isArray(arr))`

Comment: Oh. I get it now. Thanks a lot :)